# x64 Assembly highlightening/formatting in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, formatting, syntax-highlighting

1. How can I set up syntax highlighteding for x64 assembly in visual studio 2010?
2. Are there any available plug-in with 64-bit operand and SSE, SSE2, AVX opcodes?
3. What is the best way to format asm source? I mean, I would like my asm source listing look look similar to output of disassembly with nice formatting.
4. How can I get rid of annoying red underlining in asm in comments?
   Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For syntax highlightening you can look here: http://asmhighlighter.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

This works for Visual Studio 2013+
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6b069ed9-963a-430d-be66-7dace0f1f1c2